# Cannot optimize transition state

Tags: computational-chemistry

During a Gaussian scan calculation, I got a high negative frequency for a transition state candidate, but it doesn't matter what I do (Berry algorithm, qst methods) I cannot get a stable TS, I always get a really low frequency that's clear a rotation in a methyl group.

Comment: By 'scan calculation' I am assuming that you haven't done a fully relaxed optimization.  Frequencies are meaningless unless you've fully optimized a geometry to reach a minima, TS, or higher-order saddle point.  What method/basis are you using?

Comment: DFT? In that case turn the methyl group a bit and try opt=(ts,calcfc,noeigen,Verytight) and int=ultrafine.

Comment: @LordStryk, I did method 4 here https://joaquinbarroso.com/tag/qst3/ but I also ran a opt with modredundant as a keyword. With the former, I got a much negative frequency for TS candidate ("top of the scan"). I'm using  DFTB. I got a stable TS with PM6 and PBE for this structure.

Comment: @ziulfer Try DSVA's suggestion.  Be warned that DFT approaches can give rise to spurious imaginary modes of vibration (small imaginary magnitudes on the order of a few cm-1 or less).  I don't know what your trying to characterize so its hard to tell you how to get around it.  In general, try a set of functionals, increase your basis set, and use better convergence criteria.

Comment: @DSVA  I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Do you  think that a stable TS doesn't exist for my reaction doesn't exist for the DFTB Hamiltonian? I'm studying the H-transfer in this  reaction:   
      C(CH3)2(O2.)(CH2)2CH(CH3)2 --> C(CH3)2(O2H)(CH2)2C.(CH3)2